# How not to use CSS files on some pages of the site?

Tags: css, meteor, handlebars.js

How to specify which pages to load one or ong CSS files?
**For example:**

```
/ admin
--- admin.css
--- control.css
--- bootstrap.css

/ contacts
--- styles.css
--- slider.css
```

Comment: Are u Generating webpage using pure Php, code igniter or pure Html ? because if using php with any frameworks , you can specify css w.r.t pages using some if conditions.

Comment: @LetsCode You're editing a lot lately. Please make sure that you use the correct syntax hightlighting methods. Code should have surrounding "`", but not be printed in bold face.

Comment: @stefan Thanks for pointing it out. But I've not imparted on this change. I'm trying to help ppl highlight important points.

Comment: @LetsCode Yes, but you're doing it wrong. There is a standard way of highlighting code on this website and it's **not** bold. Please respect that and highlight code with "``". Then code appears like this: `code`

Answer (score 1):

Authored by [Pawel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4879/pawel)

here's a jQuery snippet:

```
$('head').append( $('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />').attr('href', 'your stylesheet url') );
```

Answer (score 0):

IF You don't want to hide that CSS, write simple map. Example:

```
var map = {};
map[ /.*\.html/ ] = [ "base.css" ];
map[ /.*\/admin\.html/ ] = [ "admin.css", "other.css" ];

var i, key, link;
for ( key in map ) {
  if ( map.hasOwnProperty( key ) && !!document.URL.match( key ) ) {
    for ( i = map[ key ].length - 1; i >= 0; --i ) {
      $('head').append( 
        $("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" />").attr(
          "href", map[ key ][ i ] ) );
    }
  }
}
```